# Open newform.aspx with prefilled values

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

How can I open a new SharePoint list item (/NewForm.aspx) with prefilled values? Thanks in advance.

RHM

Comment: Are you using the query string to pass the prefilled values to NewForm.aspx?

Answer (score 1):

If they are static values, how about setting the default Value for the field within List Settings. Browse to List, List Settings -> Columns -> Default Value.